# Ionic 3: No response on REST API call

Tags: json, rest, ionic-framework, ionic3, get-request

here's my issue:

I have this endpoint (GET) which gives me a JSON object as a result:
'localhost:3305/v1/patients'
I use Ionic 3 with the provider 'RestProvider'. 
My rest.js looks like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {
    apiUrl = 'localhost:3305/v1';
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
    }

    getPatients() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/patients').subscribe(data => {
                resolve(data);
                console.log(data);
            }, err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    patients: any;
  constructor (public restProvider: RestProvider) {
     this.getPatients();
    }

    getPatients() {
        this.restProvider.getPatients()
        .then(data => {
            this.patients = data;
            console.log(this.patients);
        });
    }
}
```

home.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>My patients</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>My patients</ion-list-header>
  </ion-list> 
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients">
      <p>{{patient}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Problem: There's no error, but there's nothing shown in the view. 
console.log(data); of rest.js shows: [object Object].

Does anyone know where the mistake is?
Thanks in regard!

Comment: Dows it return any data when you try in postman or curl?

Comment: yes, the endpoint works fine. I already tested it via Postman.

Comment: You should not have to use Promises in Angular as HttpClient uses observables. Try removing the promise funcion

Answer (score 1):

Need to rewrite  `getPatients()` code in following way:

```
getPatients() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/patients', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
    })
   .toPromise()
}
```

And Getting data in `home.ts`

```
getPatients() {
    this.restProvider.getPatients().then((res => { 
        this.patients = data;
    }, (err) => {
       console.log("rejected"); 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using modern Angular you should use http methods in accordance with docs:

In your service:

```
getPatients() {
            return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/patients')
}
```

In your component:

```
getPatients() {
        this.restProvider.getPatients()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.patients = data;
            console.log(this.patients);
        });
    }
```

Basically leverage observables as pointed out in comments

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to parse te response from the json, like this way, or the way you prefer.

```
getPatients() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/patients`).subscribe(data => {
            try {
               response = response.json();
               resolve(response);
            } catch (error) {
               console.log('[api-153]', response);
               reject(response);
            }
            console.log(data);
            resolve(data);
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```